# Monaca バックエンドのコレクションアイテムの複数同時追加

Tags: monaca

コレクションを簡易なDBとして社員名簿を作りたいとき
一定の形式をした複数人のJSONのデータ（コレクションアイテム）を
1回の追加画面で登録する方法はあるのでしょうか？

例えばmonaca導入セミナー等で紹介されていたクイズアプリの
クイズを一気に５００とか登録するケースなどです。
JSON的に工夫するしかないでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

バックマネジメントAPIを使用して、何度もPOSTするのはどうでしょうか？
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/reference/javascript/cloud_management/
http://docs.monaca.mobi/cur/ja/manual/backend/backend_management_panel/

Comment: ありがとうざいます。まさしくこの内容を知りたかったのです。よく調べていないといけませんね。たすかりました

Comment: 良かったです。よろしければ、この質問を解決扱いのステータスに変更をお願いします。